# CSS ::-webkit-scrollbar Disable Double Button

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, scrollbar

When using a custom style for a scrollbar in CSS via the `::-webkit-scrollbar` selector, then depending on the `display` property of the target element one either gets a `single-button` or a `double-button`.

See the example below, which shows different behavior for elements with `display: flex` and `display: block`.

```css
body
{
  background: #111;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper
{
  height: 150px; 
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  background: #333; 
  display: flex; 
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper > div
{
  height: 300px;
}

.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar 
{ 
  width: 16px; 
  height: 16px;
}

.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece 
{ 
  background-color: #444;
}

.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb 
{  
  background: #555;
}

.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button
{
  background: #666;
}

.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement,
.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment,
.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:decrement,
.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:increment
{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}


.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement,
.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment,
.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:decrement,
.custom-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:increment
{
  background: #AAA
}
```

```html
Device: Win10
<br />
Browser: Chrome
<br />
Goal: Custom styled scrollbar without the "double button", regardless of the display property.
<br />
<strong>Question</strong>: How to disable the "double button" completely?
<br />
<br />


<div style="display: flex">
  
  <div style="width: 30%">
    <div class="custom-scrollbar wrapper">
      <div>
        display: flex
        <br />
        scrollbar: custom
        <br />
        double-button: visible (= BAD)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div style="width: 5%">
  </div>
  <div style="width: 30%">
    <div class="custom-scrollbar wrapper" style="display: block">
      <div>
        display: block
        <br />
        scrollbar: custom
        <br />
        double-button: not visible (= GOOD)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br />
<br />

<div style="display: flex">
  
  <div style="width: 30%">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div>
        display: flex
        <br />
        scrollbar: default
        <br />
        double-button: not visible (= GOOD)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div style="width: 5%">
  </div>
  <div style="width: 30%">
    <div class="wrapper" style="display: block">
      <div>
        display: block
        <br />
        scrollbar: default
        <br />
        double-button: not visible (= GOOD)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CodePen link: https://codepen.io/Acmion/pen/VweKxZa

How do I disable the `double-button` completely?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to get rid of the double-button, use this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:start:increment,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:start:increment, 
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end:decrement 
{
    display: none;
}
```

NOTE that there are four other similar pseudo-selectors that we don't need to touch in this case:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end:increment,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:start:decrement, 
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end:increment
```

so don't get confused by other answers that include these.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the `double-button` use:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:start:increment,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end:decrement, 
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end:increment, 
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end:decrement 
{
    display: none;
}
```